# Import into SQL Server 2003 from a CSV file Error

Tags: sql-server, csv-import

I've spent so many hours just trying to import CSV, Excel data into SQL Server 2003 using SSMS (2012). I've tried importing as an excel, as a CSV, and a text file all options have presented problems of their own.

The biggest frustration now is when importing a CSV under the Flatfile option. In the Advanced tab I've set my source date column to have [DT_DBTIMESTAMP] this matches my destination's date column's type [DT_DBTIMESTAMP] YET despite all this when I run my import SQL Server errors out and says

•   Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard).

How can this fail if BOTH columns are exactly the same type?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: First, there is no SQL Server 2003, so please clarify which version you have. Second, data in a flat file is always a string until you convert it into a data structure in a programming language. It's likely that the dates are in a format that the wizard cannot correctly identify, possibly because of your locale settings. Since you didn't actually show any sample data, it's hard to say if that's the case. You might want to import the data into a `varchar` column and then convert it using TSQL, or use a full SSIS package so that you can control the locale settings on the flat file connector.

Comment: Clarification: Windows Server 2003. I'm using SSMS 2012. My text file is Tab delimitered. So I have the first row/line in the text files as my column names.

The successive rows are the different values in each row.

ex: (row1)  ID     LogID    EnterDate     LeaveDate    
    (row n) 132..  3233...  10/4/10 0:00   10/13/10 0:00

Answer (score 0):

It might not be that SQLServer is complaining about losing data when importing but when reading.  For instance, the DT_DBTIMESTAMP type expects the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff].  If your data is not formatted correct in any dimension (say your mm > 12 or dd > 31) that may be the problem.  Like @Pondlife suggested I'd bring everything into a varchar(max) field and then run TSQL to see if all rows can convert to DBTIMESTAMP data type is a simple convert statement.

Comment: The thing which confuses me is that in the "Review Data Type Mapping" screen in my import tool, there's a green checkmark in the source column where SQL Server claims that the conversion will take place in the destination column. I guess this is the naive way to just fully trust the import tool.

My dates in my text file aren't "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" as the typical date column.. So is one of the solutions to first fix this in my text file?

Also I don't have the varchar(max) field when converting.. the best I have is string[DT_STR]...and I've changed the columns to string[DT_STR] with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I saw many problems with SQL server import wizard (I'm on version 2008 R2), reading date fields from CSV files, **when format is Latin** - **day comes before the month, like 25/12/2013** (Christmas). Looks like it assume allways MM/DD/YYYY, and there is no clear way to tell to read as DD/MM/YYYY (or I did not find). If I solve, will post. Tks.